# Microsoft Azure Computer Vision faces feature cannot detect gender and age

Tags: python, computer-vision, face-detection, azure-cognitive-services

I am currently using Microsoft Azure Cognitive Services - Computer Vision API - to do image analysis, I want to use the [faces features on Azure Computer Vision API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/concept-detecting-faces) to detect person's age and gender and have followed the [code documentations and samples](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-quickstart-code/blob/9f6cb6b69e474d935644b9bd9882c10e608767fd/python/ComputerVision/ImageAnalysisQuickstart.py#L141). However, the results are **NONE**.. codes as follow (operated in Python):

```
def get_objects(f,computervision_client):
print("===== Detect Faces - local =====")
# Open local image
local_image = open(f, "rb")
# Select visual features(s) you want
local_image_features = ["faces"]
# Call API with local image and features
detect_faces_results_local = computervision_client.analyze_image_in_stream(local_image, local_image_features)

# Print results with confidence score
print("Faces in the local image: ")
if (len(detect_faces_results_local.faces) == 0):
    print("No faces detected.")
else:
    for face in detect_faces_results_local.faces:
        print("'{}' of age {} at location {}, {}, {}, {}".format(face.gender, face.age, \
        face.face_rectangle.left, face.face_rectangle.top, \
        face.face_rectangle.left + face.face_rectangle.width, \
        face.face_rectangle.top + face.face_rectangle.height))
print()
'''
END - Detect Faces - local
```

And here is the results that I get despite all the images are person's photos:

> ===== Detect Faces - local =====
> Faces in the local image:
> 'None' of age None at location 29, 51, 111, 133

> ===== Detect Faces - local =====
> Faces in the local image:
> 'None' of age None at location 51, 79, 247, 275

I am wondering if anyone has encountered any problem like this and if there is anything wrong from my code? I have also used R to extract gender and age of a single photo, but the results are **NONE** too.. This is weird.. All the features like objects, tags, colors and OCR work perfectly but not this one.. Has Microsoft Azure integrated the faces feature to their Face API instead? Any help or information will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
local_image_details = ["feature","landmarks"]
```

Is the suggested variable to add into the code block as we are missing to consider the landmarks of the image which we are uploading. The landmarks are one of the important factors and check once with the landmarks including into the code block.

Replace the below code block

```
detect_faces_results_local = computervision_client.analyze_image_in_stream(local_image, local_image_features)
```

with

```
results_local = computervision_client.analyze_image(local_image_url , local_image_url_image_features, local_image_url_image_details)
```

by changing the variable names according to the requirement.

Comment: Have tried this and "feature" details are not available, there are only "celebrities" and "landmarks" unfortunately :( and if I use celebrities and landmarks it did not work as I need to retrieve approval from them. Is it the case that I still need to retrieve approval eventho I do not try detecting celebrities faces and only want to know gender and age of the people on the photos?